# Improve the efficiency of the algorithm

Tags: scala

I'm trying to improve the algorithm.
Now it works for O(n) and iterates through all the elements of the set. Always. My attempts to achieve incomplete O(n) lead to the introduction of var variables. It would be great to do without var.

Task:
We need a class that implements a list of company names by substring - from the list of all available names, output a certain number of companies
that start with the entered line.
It is assumed that the class will be called when filling out a form on a website/mobile application with a high RPS (Requests per second).

My solution:

```
class SuggestService(companyNames : Seq[String]) {

  def suggest(input: String, numberOfSuggest : Int) : Seq[String] = {
    val resultCompanyNames =
    for {
      name <- companyNames if input.equals(name.take(input.length))
    } yield name

    resultCompanyNames.take(numberOfSuggest)
  } //TODO: My code

}
```

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/mIC5ZTGwRyKnuJAbhM1VlA

Comment: The algorithm already looks good enough. Next trick is to introduce caching. Reddis or memcached will do fine. Also on the frontend, don't send a query every keystroke. Use windows of 150ms after the last keystroke to decide when to send a query

Comment: Have you tried making `resultCompanyNames` lazy?

Comment: `companyNames.view.filter(_.startsWith(input)).take(numberOfSuggest).toSeq`

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by @jwvh in the comments:

```
companyNames.view.filter(_.startsWith(input)).take(numberOfSuggest).toSeq
```

is good when you have several dozen company names, but in the worst case you'll have to check every single company name. If you have thousands of company names and many requests per second, this has a chance to become a serious bottleneck.

A better approach might be to sort the company names and use binary search to find the first potential result in `O(L log N)`, where `L` is the average length of a company name:

```
import scala.collection.imuutable.ArraySeq // in Scala 2.13

class SuggestService(companyNames: Seq[String]) {
  // in Scala 2.12 use companyNames.toIndexedSeq.sorted
  private val sortedNames = companyNames.to(ArraySeq).sorted 

  @annotation.tailrec
  private def binarySearch(input: String, from: Int = 0, to: Int = sortedNames.size): Int = {
    if (from == to) from
    else {
      val cur = (from + to) / 2
      if (sortedNames(cur) < input) binarySearch(input, cur + 1, to)
      else binarySearch(input, from, cur)
    }
  }

  def suggest(input: String, numberOfSuggest: Int): Seq[String] = {
    val start = binarySearch(input)
    sortedNames.view
      .slice(start, start + numberOfSuggest)
      .takeWhile(_.startsWith(input))
      .toSeq
  }
}
```

Note that the built-in binary search in scala (`sortedNames.search`) returns *any* result, not necessarily the first one. And the built-in binary search from Java works either on `Array`s (`Arrays.binarySearch`) or on Java collections (`Collections.binarySearch`). So in the code above I've provided an explicit implementation of the lower bound binary search.

---

If you need still better performance, you can use a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. After traversing the trie and finding the node corresponding to `input` in `O(L)` (may depend on trie implementation), you can then continue down from this node to retrieve the first `numberOfSuggest` results. The query time doesn't depend on `N` at all, so you can use this method with millions company names.

Comment: I really like the solution using binary search. It is very simple and effective. But my search for a solution led me to the idea that using a prefix tree is the most efficient. You confirmed this at the end. I will try to implement a tree. If I understand correctly, then first I need to implement the tree inside the SuggestService class.

Comment: If you only ever look for the start of the word then a prefix tree is the way to go. Building the word list from a full tree will be slow as there are many nodes to visit, so maybe truncate the tree after a few letters and switch to linear search on much smaller lists, which keeping list building efficient as well.